# c# Run cmd and watch the result is in cmd

Tags: c#, cmd

I’m suffering with a problem for a month, I want to run the cmd command "sfc / scannow", before that I tried to read the result of this command via StandartOutput, but it’s not working with this command, I had an idea to press the button to call the console with this command and watch the result is in cmd, but I have a problem again, I just have cmd and everything is open, the command is not executed.I need to run the sfc / scannow command and see the process and the result of the check, in any way, but using C # (the project was created on win.forms)Please, help me

Also work with other cmd commands, I read through StandartOutput, but it doesn’t work with this command

```cs
string strCmdText;
            strCmdText = "sfc/scannow";
            Process cmdSFC = Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                UseShellExecute = true,
                WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Windows\System32",
                FileName = @"C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe",
                Arguments = "/c " + strCmdText,

            });
  cmdSFC.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: You do need a space in that command `sfc /scannow`

Comment: See if this help: [How do I get output from a command to appear in a control on a Form in real-time?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51682585/7444103).

Comment: The point is not in the space , the point is in the "sfc / scannow" command itself

Answer (score 0):

Set `UseShellExecute` to `false`. As described in [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.useshellexecute?view=netframework-4.8#remarks):

> Setting this property to `false` enables you to redirect input, output, and error streams.