# Is it possible to run code while a WaitForExit process is active?

Tags: c#, process, overlay, clock

I'm trying to add an overlay clock to a program that basically displays the time. However, it also opens Powerpoint Shows that act as advertisements. I've added a second time display via a form and label overtop the powerpoint, but because I'm relying on the Process.WaitForExit() function I'm unable to update the clock while the powerpoint is running. How do I solve this?

What the powerpoint code looks like:

```
PptxClock p = new PptxClock();
Process powerPoint = new Process();

//Start the time display over the powerpoint slides
p.Show();

 //Now it's time to open the powerpoint
powerPoint.StartInfo.FileName = ppfile;
powerPoint.Start();
// increment the counter so next iteration we play the next file in the list
slidetoplay += 1;

powerPoint.WaitForExit();
//The powerpoint should be over by this point. Disable the clock now.
p.Close();
```

What I want to run during powerPoint.WaitForExit():

```
private Timer ChangeTime;

//Run SetPos and WhatWeek as soon as the form loads
private void PptxClock_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
UpdateTime();
SetTimer();
}

public void UpdateTime()
{
OverlayTime.Text = "Time: " + DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss") + ".";
}

//Set the timer
private void SetTimer()
{
    ChangeTime = new Timer
    {
        Enabled = true,
        Interval = 500
    };
    ChangeTime.Tick += new EventHandler(ChangeTime_Tick);
    ChangeTime.Start();
}


//Update the time every tick. We only need the time for this simple form.
//The timer declaration is required to do this.
private void ChangeTime_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OverlayTime.Text = "Time: " + DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss") + ".";
    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss"));

}
```

I just want to be able to change the contents of the p form's time label.

Comment: Use the event-driven version. Set [EnableRaisingEvents = true;](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.enableraisingevents) and subscribe to the [Exited](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.exited) event (removing `.WaitForExit()`, of course). This won't block. [Sample code here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51682585/7444103).