# Why the console window shown even if i set it to be hidden?

Tags: c#, process, console-application

How can I get rid of the console window? I have the ProcessStartInfo as below

```
   var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
    {
       FileName = Path.Combine(path, "Hi.exe");,
       WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
       UseShellExecute = false,
       CreateNoWindow = true,
        RedirectStandardInput = true,
     };
      Process.Start(processStartInfo).StandardInput.WriteLine(argHandlerArgs);
```

Comment: `processStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true`

Comment: It is already set to true

Comment: Yes, sorry, that thing I was writing on got to my nerves. I mean, if that `Hi.exe` is a Console app, use just `CreateNoWindow = true`, remove `WindowStyle` so it won't get in the way and add `.RedirectStandardError = True`.

Comment: That didn't work either

Comment: You're doing something wrong (your code here won't compile). See the sample code here: [How do I get output from a command to appear in a control on a Form in real-time?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51682585/7444103), take it as it is and try again. I'm not saying that it will work for you - I don't know what your Console app is doing (or what you're doing) - but it usually does :)

Answer (score 0):

> Why the console window shown even if i set it to be hidden?

As per [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processwindowstyle?view=netcore-3.1):

> To use Hidden, the UseShellExecute property must be true.

But you have set `UseShellExecute` to be `false`.

*If your process is short running, consider using `Minimized` instead.*

Comment: Then perhaps use `Minimized` @user173092?