# How to pipe output from console cmd to TextBox from another class

Tags: c#, winforms, frameworks

There is a `NewClass.cs` in which I collect data about `ipconfig` from cmd. How can I output data from this class (via arguments) to the `TextBox` that lies on the form ?!

```
public static class NewClass
{
     public static void Test()
     {
         ProcessStartInfo Info = new ProcessStartInfo
         {
            FileName = "cmd.exe",
            Arguments = "ipconfig /all",
            CreateNoWindow = false,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal
         };
         Process result = Process.Start(Info);
         result.WaitForExit();
    }
}
```

On the form lies a TextBox, you need to make a call to the Test method (with passing arguments) from the `NewClass.cs` class so that everything from the command line (cmd.exe) is displayed in this `TextBox` without the console appearing.
How to implement this? \

---

I tried like this but it doesn't work\

```
private void button1_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IProgress<string> progress = new Progress<string>(s =>
    {
        textBox1.Text += s;
    });
    NewClass.Test(progress);
}

public static class NewClass
{
    public static void Test(IProgress<string> progress)
    {
        Process process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        process.StartInfo.Arguments = "ipconfig /all";
        process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        process.StartInfo.StandardOutputEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(866);
        process.StartInfo.StandardErrorEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(866);
        var handler = new DataReceivedEventHandler((s, e) => progress?.Report(e.Data));
        process.OutputDataReceived += handler;
        process.ErrorDataReceived += handler;
        process.Start();
        process.BeginOutputReadLine();
    }
}
```

Help Please

Comment: See the methods (and the notes) shown here: [How do I get output from a command to appear in a control on a Form in real-time?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51682585/7444103). In your case, set `Arguments = "START /WAIT /K ipconfig /all"`. Don't use `IProgress` here, it's not needed: see the `SinchronizingObject` property (use the Form, not the TexBox/RichTextBox)