# How to run bat file with shell function in VB.NET without showing command

Tags: vb.net, shell

I need to run exe file on command prompt to pass some parameters and in the code of exe file i have run a bat file using VB.NET built-in `shell` method, but when run exe file on command prompt the shell method seems printed the entire code of the bat file out into cmd, this is not allowed.
Example:

```vb
Shell("any code and path to file", AppWinStyle.Hide)
```

**Note:**  I have to run this bat file with shell method of VB.NET

Comment: Use the `Process` class. You can specify arguments as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51682585/7444103) (see the commented lines on top of the `StartCmdProcess()` method) and also the visibility of the Command prompt (also described there).

Comment: @Jimi, I'm only allowed to run with shell methods and edit the `"any code and path to file"` part

Comment: Well, try `Shell("Some path", AppWinStyle.Hide, True)`