# Preserving basic application functions when using StandardInput/Output redirection

Tags: vb.net, redirect, textbox, streamwriter, redirectstandardoutput

I’m trying to run an external (non-GUI) application and use RedirectStandardInput and RedirectStandardOutput to send data to and receive data from this application to a TextBox. The main problem is that this application uses a command prompt to interact with the user:

> IBM Spectrum Protect Command Line Administrative Interface - Version
> 8, Release 1, Level 15.0 (c) Copyright by IBM Corporation and other(s)
> 1990, 2022. All Rights Reserved.
>
> Session established with server SERVER1: Linux/x86_64   Server Version
> 8, Release 1, Level 13   Server date/time: 08-11-2022 13:54:54
> Last access: 08-11-2022 13:41:51
>
> Protect: SERVER1>

At this prompt, you can enter commands, which can return a lot of output, that’s why this application prompts the user for enter, to scroll through each screen:

> Protect: SERVER1>help
>
> Command line Help for the IBM Spectrum Protect for Linux server
> Version 8.1.13
>
> Contents
>
> 1.0 Managing the server from the command line
>
> 1.1 Issuing commands from the administrative client
>
> ```
> 1.1.1 Starting and stopping the administrative client
>
> 1.1.2 Monitoring server activities from the administrative client
>
> 1.1.3 Monitoring removable-media mounts from the administrative client
>
> 1.1.4 Processing individual commands from the administrative client
>
> 1.1.5 Processing a series of commands from the administrative client
>
> 1.1.6 Formatting output from commands
>
> 1.1.7 Saving command output to a specified location
>
> 1.1.8 Administrative client options more...   (<ENTER> to continue, 'C' to cancel)
> ```

Here, the user can use the enter key to go to the next screen or enter ‘c’ to cancel the command.
I currently use a form with TextBox1 for input and TextBox2 for output. The downside is that I no longer see the command prompt `SERVER1>`. Also, the scroll-one-page-at-a-time feature is also no longer working, *all* output is written to TextBox2 in one go.
I have two questions:

1. Is it at all possible to use one single Textbox for both input and
   output, just like the original window does?
2. How can I make sure all lines are written to StandardOutput, so
   including the command prompt and also including the `more...   (<ENTER> to continue, 'C' to cancel)` when command output is more than one page?

Please find my current code down below. Thank you very much for any help in advance!

Kind regards,
Eric van Loon

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim WithEvents P As New Process
    Dim SW As System.IO.StreamWriter
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        P.EnableRaisingEvents = True
        Me.Text = "My title"
        AddHandler P.OutputDataReceived, AddressOf DisplayOutput
        P.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow() = True
        P.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
        P.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = True
        P.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
        P.StartInfo.FileName = "dsmadmc.exe"
        P.StartInfo.Arguments = ""
        P.Start()
        P.SynchronizingObject = Me
        P.BeginOutputReadLine()
        SW = P.StandardInput
        SW.WriteLine()
    End Sub
    Private Sub DisplayOutput(ByVal sendingProcess As Object, ByVal output As DataReceivedEventArgs)
        TextBox1.AppendText(output.Data() & vbCrLf)
    End Sub
    Private Sub Textbox2_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox2.KeyPress
        If e.KeyChar = Chr(Keys.Return) Then
            SW.WriteLine(TextBox2.Text)
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub myProcess_Exited(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles P.Exited
        Me.Close()
    End Sub End Class
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running an external app in textbox (how to preserve all functionality?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74349449/running-an-external-app-in-textbox-how-to-preserve-all-functionality)

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51682585/10024425

Comment: Hi @user9938,
I found a fix for the prompt issue, so that's fixed now.
I tried (also the code from the page in your second update) and it's not working for my application.
Basically, it's also not working for a simple cmd.exe. If you start cmd.exe outside of VB and enter `dir /p c:\windows` you get one screen at a time. If you start cmd.exe and redirect input and output to a textbox, the /p switch no longer seems to be working and the whole output is showed.