# Write to process StandardInput

Tags: c#, shell, remote-access

I am doing remote CMD shell. After writing to `StandardInput` i need to read output from `StandardOutput` but for it i need to close `StandardInput`. How i can write to `StandardInput` again?

```cs
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
process.Start();

process.StandardInput.WriteLine("dir");
process.StandardInput.Close();
nextOutput = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
```

Comment: Why do you "need to close StandardInput". If you just want to ensure your input it sent, you can flush the input stream for the "cmd.exe".

Comment: @dash-o, i tried to flush `StandardInput` but it freezes at `process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()`. As i understand, `StandardOutput` is empty

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get output from a command to appear in a control on a Form in real-time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51680382/how-do-i-get-output-from-a-command-to-appear-in-a-control-on-a-form-in-real-time)