# Check Command Prompt silently if it is waiting for User C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, input, cmd, process

I am working on WPF and C# for creating IDE for my language called [EasyBite](https://github.com/Dangujba/EasyBite), i added a Output panel to IDE to display output of contacted CMD using Process, everything is working fine, until the program has an Input. It will terminate the execution once it reaches the input. If it is in CMD everything is okay.

The logic is: I am passing the EasyBite interpreter  and file name as argument using the Process and here is the code:

```
private void StartEasyBiteProcess(string filePath, string compilerPath)
        {
            Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                
                OutputTextBox.AppendText("EasyBite Executing...\n\n");

                
                OutputTextBox.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
            });
            _easyBiteProcess = new Process();
            _easyBiteProcess.StartInfo.FileName = Path.Combine(compilerPath, "EasyBite.exe") ; 
            _easyBiteProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = filePath; // Pass the file path as a command-line argument
            _easyBiteProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            _easyBiteProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            _easyBiteProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            _easyBiteProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            _easyBiteProcess.OutputDataReceived += EasyBiteProcess_OutputDataReceived;
            _easyBiteProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            _easyBiteProcess.Exited += EasyBiteProcess_Exited;
            _easyBiteProcess.Start();

            _easyBiteProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();
            foreach(ProcessThread thread in process.Threads)
    if (thread.ThreadState == ThreadState.Wait
        && thread.WaitReason == ThreadWaitReason.UserRequest)
              _waitForInput = true;

        }
        private void EasyBiteProcess_Exited(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                OutputTextBox.Text += "EasyBite program exited.\n";
                OutputTextBox.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
            });
        }
        private void EasyBiteProcess_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {

            Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                if (_waitForInput)
                {
                    OutputTextBox.IsReadOnly = false;
                    // Handle user input
                    HandleProgramInput(e.Data);
                    _waitForInput = false;  // Assuming that the input handling is synchronous and only for one line
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Read();
                    // Handle program output
                    OutputTextBox.AppendText("> " + e.Data + "\n");
                    OutputTextBox.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
                    OutputTextBox.CaretIndex = OutputTextBox.Text.Length;
                    OutputTextBox.ScrollToEnd(); // Scrolls to the end of the TextBox
                }
            });
        }

        private void HandleProgramInput(string userInput)
        {
            // Write user input to the standard input stream of EasyBite.exe
            using (StreamWriter streamWriter = _easyBiteProcess.StandardInput)
            {
                if (streamWriter.BaseStream.CanWrite)
                {
                    streamWriter.WriteLine(userInput);
                }
            }

            OutputTextBox.AppendText("> " + userInput + "\n");
            OutputTextBox.CaretIndex = OutputTextBox.Text.Length;
            OutputTextBox.ScrollToEnd();
            // Scrolls to the end of the TextBox
        }
```

I found this here on Stackoverflow but not working

```
foreach(ProcessThread thread in process.Threads)
    if (thread.ThreadState == ThreadState.Wait
        && thread.WaitReason == ThreadWaitReason.UserRequest)
```

I will appreciate if someone can help. Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of your [[tag:cmd]] tag. Not only is cmd.exe not mentioned as a prerequsite for your program, (it states 'command line', 'command prompt or terminal'), you've told us that there is no problem when you specifically use it. IMO this is unnecessary spamming of a tag.

Comment: The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51682585/10024425

Comment: @user246821i checked it, but it seems to be different from my problem, the main question is how can detect if command prompt is waiting for an input?

Comment: @MuhammadBabaGoni, I'll ask again, slightly differently. How is cmd.exe, (Command Prompt), relevant? Your program page does not mention it is needed. The default in Windows is now powershell.exe, (PowerShell Prompt), and the default shell is wt.exe, (Windows Terminal). The code you have posted above does not mention `cmd`, i.e. it does not explicitly open it. It seems from your question that when the end user runs direcly from an already opened Command Prompt, there's no issue, so you're implying that your program is somehow using it if not opened from within it. How is it doing that?

Comment: @Compo Sorry for my English. Actually i am talking about cmd.exe. Normally, when you install the EasyBite compiler (the language i want to create the IDE for) you can use cmd (command prompt) to run program written in EasyBite by command “EasyBite filename.bite”. So now in the IDE when you click on run button i used process class to pass the command (EasyBite filename.bite) to the cmd and take back the result to display in output panel, but when the program required input, i want to know so that i will activate input panel to make the input and continue with running.

Comment: @Compo that's the interpreter will interpret the other statement and once it reaches the input statement i wnat to know so that input will be provided and continue continue with execution. Thank you.

Comment: I do not see anything in your code which is specifically opening cmd.exe. Please explain to me where it is doing so, and how? Your code seems to show opening the process `EasyBite.exe`. I assume therefore that internally EasyBite must be specifically calling on `cmd.exe`. If that is the case, then in order to diagnose a problem with that, we need to see the code which is doing so. I cannot see it in what you have posted.

Comment: @Compo _easyBiteProcess.StartInfo.FileName = Path.Combine(compilerPath, "EasyBite.exe") ;

Comment: Sorry the problem is with me, i just come to realize that i am not actually communicating with cmd, rather with process. Is there any way i can detect if the process waiting for input?

Comment: So, if you open Windows Terminal and use a PowerShell tab; or open a PowerShell Prompt window, then type ```"P:\athTo\EasyBite.exe" "P:\athTo\filename.bite"```, which is a proper command line, _(not that shortened, unreliable, and less efficient ```EasyBite filename.bite``` command line)_, what happens? Does it work in exactly the same way as it does when run from a Command Prompt tab and/or window?